# GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener onCameraChange works with delays

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I need to listen CameraPosition changes to draw a custom compass. The problem that: `GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener onCameraChange`

- this listener may not be notified of intermediate camera positions.
- it fires with random delays (can not understand why)

Is there are any way to listen to CameraPosition bearing changes? (In ios f.e. it's possible to achieve using Key-Value Observing), reflection...?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put FrameLayout above map and catch touches:

```
@Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        if (mCatchTouchFrameLayoutListener != null)
            mCatchTouchFrameLayoutListener.onTouch(ev);
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To move the camera instantly with the given CameraUpdate, you can call `GoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdate)`.

You can make the user experience more pleasing, especially for short moves, by animating the change. To do this instead of calling `GoogleMap.moveCamera()` call `GoogleMap.animateCamera()`. The map will move smoothly to the new attributes. The most detailed form of this method, `GoogleMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate, duration, callback)`, offers three arguments:

> CameraUpdate: The CameraUpdate describing where to move the camera.
>
> Callback: An object that implements GoogleMap.CancellableCallback. This generalized interface for handling tasks defines two methods `onCancel()` and `onFinished()`. For animation, the methods are called in the following circumstances:
>   onFinish()
>   Invoked if the animation goes to completion without interruption.
>   onCancel()
>   Invoked if the animation is interrupted by calling stopAnimation() or starting a new camera movement.
>   Alternatively, this can also occur if you call GoogleMap.stopAnimation().
>
> Duration: Desired duration of the animation, in milliseconds, as an `int`.

Comment: How does this answer the question?