# How detect when user moves the map in android?

Tags: android, maps, listener, android-mapview

I have a mapview in my app, I want to detect when the user moves the map and hide a imageview that I have, and then detect when the user stop move the map for show up the imageView once again.

Answer (score 3):

you can use **OnCameraMoveStartedListener** or **OnCameraIdleListener**

```
mMap.setOnCameraMoveStartedListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCameraMoveStarted(int reason) {
        // code
        // REASON_API_ANIMATION
        // REASON_DEVELOPER_ANIMATION
        // REASON_GESTURE
    }
});

mMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCameraIdle() {
         // code
    }
});
```

see this [link](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener)

Answer (score 0):

try this:-

```
mapView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }else{
            imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: mapView doesn't work with setOnTouchListener. but my GoogleMap map work but doesn't have setOnTouchListener.

Answer (score 0):

Use either the GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener but this doesn't get called immediatly when you move the map. Or like in this thread [intercept touch events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28819522/googlemap-oncamerachangelistener-oncamerachange-works-with-delays) from a transparent framelayout which you have to put over the map.